# How to determine how many entries exceed a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset listed below.

```
##       ID        DOB sector cumula Oct   Res_FROM     Res_TO   Exp_FROM
## 1  20100 1979-08-24    H38   6400   W 1979-08-15 1991-05-15 1979-08-24
## 2  20101 1980-05-05    B01   1600  NW 1980-05-15 1991-04-15 1980-05-15
## 3  20102 1979-03-17    H04   1600  SW 1972-06-15 1979-08-15 1979-03-17
## 4  20103 1981-11-30    B09   3200  NE 1982-01-15 1984-01-15 1982-01-15
## 5  20104 1981-11-30    B37   8000   N 1984-01-15 1986-04-15 1984-01-15
## 6  20105 1978-09-01    B09   3200  NE 1982-01-15 1984-01-15 1982-01-15
```

I am wanting to take the cumulative column and identify how many individuals (each ID number is an individual) exceed a certain value. For this, let's say I want to know how many people (ID entries) exceed a cumulative value of 3000. How would I get this number/result? I have over 14,000 rows of data, but for simplicity sake I just included the top 6 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df` is your dataset:

```
df[df$cumula > 3000,]
```

will give you the entries that exceed 3000.

If you only need to count how many, you can do

```
sum(df$cumula > 3000)
```